# /users/{id}/badges - multiple identical results

Tags: bug, status-completed, users, badges

Each badge returned in the list of results from `/users/{id}/badges` already contains an `award_count` indicating how many times the badge was awarded for the particular `user` attached to the badge. In addition to that, it returns `award_count` copies of that exact same badge data. For an example see http://api.stackoverflow.com/0.8/users/1/badges. There are 31 copies of the Nice Answer badge, each showing an award count of 31.

There should be at most one copy of any badge returned per user ID in the `id` vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed.